# Composer exception after deleting a working connection profile

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have removed a connection profile that was actually in use, now I am receiving the following error:

```
Error: Failed to load connection profile Online Profile. Error was Error: ENOENT: No such file or directory., '/.composer-connection-profiles/Online Profile/connection.json'
```

I did login to the docker instance for the composer and the file exists in the /home/composer. I tried to move it to the root to match the exception, however I do not have the right permission to do so.

My question is, is there any other place that the selected profile is saved in so that I can set it to another existing profile? is their nay other way to solve this issue?

Comment: connection profiles when stored in the file system are always looked for in .composer-connection-profiles of the users home directory. Not sure how that error message would point to the root directory unless it was perhaps running under the root user ?

Comment: I have investigated the directories, and yes they are (eventually) stored in the file system, however even with the files there still the same result

Comment: Can you provide details of how you created the problem including how do downloaded and started composer and whether you are using command line tools, playground etc.